# Fixed header not fixed when there is horizontal overflow

Tags: css, css-position, horizontal-scrolling, mobile-browser

I have a header with a fixed position and a width of 100%. It's working as expected on desktop, but not in mobile browsers (Chrome, Opera and Edge).
I'm testing on Android 5.1 if that makes a difference.

When there is horizontal overflow, the header is no longer fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by setting `overflow: auto` on **both** `html` and `body`.

EDIT: doing that makes the header go over the scrollbar.
The actual fix is adding `user-scalable=no` to `<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>`

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607215/fixed-positioned-header-persists-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile#18607841)