# Fixed header is over scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, overflow, css-position, mobile-browser

I have a fixed header which is hiding the top part of the scrollbar.
It's caused by setting `overflow: auto` on both `hmtl` and `body`.
However, if I don't do that, it breaks the floating header on mobile browsers (except Firefox).

I'm not sure what to do here, it seems I either have the header over the scrollbar or a broken fixed header on mobile browsers.

[Here's an example.](https://ezrazebra.net/snippets/fixedheader.html)

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%; width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    header {
        position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
        width: 100%; height: 7.5em;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `overflow: auto` from `body` and added `user-scalable=no` to `<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport'>`. That does the trick.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607215/fixed-positioned-header-persists-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile#18607841)