# position: sticky using react.semantic-ui Table collection

Tags: css, reactjs

I created a basic table and want to freeze the header and first column.  It works on the desktop.  However, when I click on the Toogle device toolbar in the console, the stickiness goes away on the responsive options.  I am trying to figure out how to make the stickiness work on the responsive options.

here is the js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Icon, Menu, Table, Segment } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import './style.css';


const TableExamplePagination = () => (
    <Table celled striped unstackable className='freeze-head-and-col'>
    {/* definition prop overrides the style.css
        adding the unstackable prop let the formatting show up on mobile, but the stickiness does not work */}
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell></Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Header</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>

      <Table.Body>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>

        ...

        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Fixed</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>Cell</Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Body>
    </Table>
)

export default TableExamplePagination;
```

here is the css code:

```
body {
    overflow: visible;  /*It seems like the default is overflow-x: hidden;*/
}

/*Fix the header to the top*/
.freeze-head-and-col tr:first-of-type th{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: cyan;
}

/*Fix the first column  to the left*/
.freeze-head-and-col td:first-of-type{
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: red;
  left: 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Edit: corner fixed always */
.freeze-head-and-col tr:first-of-type th:first-of-type{
  z-index:100;
  left: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Can anyone explain why the stickiness works on the desktop, but not on the responsive options?

Comment: Maybe this can explain it, https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-and-table-headers/

Comment: thanks.  I used that to get me this far...

Answer (score 0):

This helped explain why it did not work:
layout/virtual viewport versus visual viewport on mobile

in index.html:
`<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' name='viewport'>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
https://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html

[Fixed positioned header persists on desktop but not on mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607215/fixed-positioned-header-persists-on-desktop-but-not-on-mobile)